# Manipulating csv files in python

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I have been trying to do the following in a long csv file with three columns:

for every row, getting the max and min of the entries of the previous 250 rows. The data is like this - column 1 is an index (1-5300), column 2 is where the data is and column 3 is another one, but not used here. This is the code I have till now. Note that 'i' is the row index which looks at column 1. Column 2 is where the data is stored (i.e. the data whose max and min I want).

The problem I have is that the csv.reader starts at the end of the file always and throws the whole algorithm out of the window. Don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help

```
max1 = 0
min1 = 1000000    

i = 3476
f1=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv')
file_reader = csv.reader(f1)
for col in file_reader:
    serial          = int(col[0])
    if serial <i-250:
        spyy = float(col[1])
        print spyy

    for j in range(0,250):
        spyy = float(col[1])          
        max1 = max(max1,spyy)
        min1 = min(min1,spyy)
        file_reader.next()
        #print spyy

f1.close()

print 'max =' +str(max1) + 'min = ' + str(min1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, this line

```
for col in file_reader:
```

is actually iterating through the *lines* or *rows* of the file, not the columns

and for each `col`, you later advance the reader 250 lines in this code

```
for j in range(0,250):
    spyy = float(col[1]) # here you're grabbing the same second item 250 times
    max1 = max(max1,spyy) # setting the new max to the same value 250 times
    min1 = min(min1,spyy) # setting the new min to the same value 250 times
    file_reader.next() # now you advance, but col is the same so ...
    # it's like you're skipping 250 lines
```

this means that each row stored in `col` is actually 250 lines after the previous row stored in `col`. It's like your skipping through the file in steps of 250.

I rewrote it, based on what you said you wanted to do. See if this makes more sense:

```
f1=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv')
file_reader = csv.reader(f1)

spyy_values = []
mins = []
maxes = []

# just saying 'for x in file_reader' is all you need to iterate through the rows
# you don't need to use file_reader.next()
# here I'm also using the enumerate() function
# which automatically returns an index for each row
for row_index, row in enumerate(file_reader):
    # get the value
    spyy_values.append( float(row[1]) )

    if row_index >= 249:
        # get the min of the last 250 values,
        # including this line
        this_min = min(spyy_values[-250:])
        mins.append(this_min)
        # get the max of the last 250 values,
        # including this line
        this_max = max(spyy_values[-250:])
        maxes.append(this_max)

print "total max:", max(maxes)
print "total min:", min(mins)
print "you have %s max values" % len(maxes)
print "you have %s min values" % len(mins)
print "here are the maxes", maxes
print "here are the mins", mins
```

Keep in mind that csv.reader is an *iterator*, so the for loop will automatically advance through each line. Check out [the example in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGolder ... you pointed the right error. Solution is exactly what I need!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing file_reader.next() at the incorrect place. As per the code you posted, file_reader.next() would get executed within the inner FOR loop, this may be the reason it ends up at the EOF after processing the first column itself.

The correct code would be:

```
max1 = 0
min1 = 1000000    

i = 3476
f1=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv')
file_reader = csv.reader(f1)
for col in file_reader:
    serial          = int(col[0])
    if serial <i-250:
        spyy = float(col[1])
        print spyy

    for j in range(0,250):
        spyy = float(col[1])          
        max1 = max(max1,spyy)
        min1 = min(min1,spyy)
# you move to the next row after processing the current row
file_reader.next()
 #print spyy

f1.close()

print 'max =' +str(max1) + 'min = ' + str(min1)
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks Prahalad - but now this is giving me the "stopiteration" errr on the file_reader_next. I think it is going to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first two columns are numbers this may help you.
You may readlines and split by "," on your own. (Just a workaround).

Use

```
file_reader=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv').readlines()
for line in file_reader:
    col = line.split(",")
    serial          = int(col[0])
```

in place of

```
f1=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv')
file_reader = csv.reader(f1)
for col in file_reader:
   serial          = int(col[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Archit - but how do I move to the next line once I am using 'line' in the file reader.

Comment: The for loop should essentially do that. In one iteration of loop you process the one line and in next iteration you get the next line.

Comment: I ran this code but wasn't doing that exactly... many thanks though. Benjamin and Steve got me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
f1=  open('PUT/PUT_SELLING.csv')
file_reader = csv.reader(f1)
which_str = raw_input('Comma seperated list of indices to show: ')
which_to_show = [int(i) for i in which_str.split(',')]
vals = []
for cols in file_reader:  # This will iteratate the rows
    vals.append(float(col[1]))  # Accumulate the results
    index = int(cols[0])
    if index > 249:      # enough to show min,max
        mini = (min(vals))  # add to vals
        maxi = (max(vals))
        del vals[0]  # remove the first entry
    if index in which_to_show:
         print 'index %d min=%f max=%f' % (index, mini, maxi)  # Format vals

f1.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve ... this looks very close and quite elegant. How can I modify it so that for every i (=3428 in col[0] e.g.), I can find the max and min of numbers stored in indexes 3178 to 3428 in col[1]. I need to input 'i' and output both max and min of that range

Comment: this does it too... many thanks!... can I select two answers?

Comment: I am afraid not - there has been a fair bit of debate on this over on Meta but currently the answer is No!  All you can do - if/when you have the reputation for it - is to up vote the unaccepted answer.